# Problem with VirtualBox 5.2 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 17.10, dpkg

First of all I want to say I'm really new to Ubuntu, and is
the first time im using VirtualBox on Ubuntu too.

I installed VirtualBox 5.2 on Ubuntu 17.10,
after installation, I created a new virtual machine,
when i run it i get these errors:

[image: VBox Error]

[image: VBox Error2]

After I run the command 'modprobe vboxdrv' I get this:

[image: Modprobe error result]

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kbuild libsdl-ttf2.0-0 linux-headers-4.13.0-16
  linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-32
  linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-16-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-32-generic
  module-assistant
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/648 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 332694 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.10.2_all.deb ...
Deleting module version: 5.1.34
completely from the DKMS tree.
Done.
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.10.2) over (5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.10.2) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.1.34-dfsg-0ubuntu1.17.10.2) ...
Loading new virtualbox-5.1.34 DKMS files...
Building for 4.14.18-041418-generic
Building initial module for 4.14.18-041418-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.14.18-041418-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.14.18-041418-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.34/build/make.log for more information.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-04-22 16:56:13 CST; 11ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 7794 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu virtualbox[7794]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu virtualbox[7794]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu virtualbox[7794]:    ...fail!
abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
abr 22 16:56:13 DavidUbuntu systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is the part I'm not understanding:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.14.18-041418-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.14.18-041418-generic (x86_64)
```

I've searched this errors on the internet and tried a lot of things, uninstalled several times and re-installed, but I'm still getting this errors.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the kernel from 4.14 to 4.15

I'm really new to Ubuntu so I did'nt understand why the kernel had to do with Vbox, but that apparently solved it.

Thanks for anyone that spend time on this question.

Comment: If you are new to Ubuntu, you really shouldn't use the unofficial, unsupported "Mainline" kernel builds.